# What is happening during module/package imports

Tags: python

Can anyone help me understand what happens behind the scenes when I import a module in Python? Is there any memory or processing overhead associated with importing? Or is it more like opening a door to extend the local namespace? I don't really need specifics, just a general idea.

I'm also hoping to understand what happens when a full package is imported, when there is no `__init__.py` inside the package folder (only Python 3+, I think).

Also, what changes when that package is imported into a module that is part of the package being imported? Does Python automate the `__init__.py` based on where the package is being imported? If it does do something smart like this, does that mean it is actually better to avoid writing the package `__init__.py`?

My main reason for asking these questions is to know what I should and shouldn't do as far as importing goes. It seems convenient to just import a package and use whatever I want from it without worrying about which specific modules I need. But I don't know the full impact of doing something like this.

Edit: I just wanted to add the important detail that my modules are all already loaded into memory.

Comment: Recommend this https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html